# Saving an Image stored in BytesIO in pillow

Tags: python-imaging-library, image-compression

I have an image stored as BytesIO of Pillow and I need to save it to a file with some header information (containing textual attributes) that I need to add specific to my problem. I need the bytes to be represented according to some  image compression format. Would that be possible? If yes, how it can be done?
I also need to store more than one image in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing more than one image in a file is problematic for PNG, JPEG and the most of the common formats. One option for that is TIFF - not sure if that works for you?

Here's how you can store some additional text in a PNG at least:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL.PngImagePlugin import Image, PngInfo

# Create empty metadata and add a couple of text strings
metadata = PngInfo()
metadata.add_text("Key1:","Value1")
metadata.add_text("Key2:","Value2")

# Create red image and save with metadata embedded
im = Image.new('RGB',(64,64),'red')
im.save("result.png", pnginfo=metadata)
```

[image]

If you check that with `pngcheck` you will see:

```
pngcheck -7v result.png
```

**Sample Output**

```
File: result.png (200 bytes)
  chunk IHDR at offset 0x0000c, length 13
    64 x 64 image, 24-bit RGB, non-interlaced
  chunk tEXt at offset 0x00025, length 12, keyword: Key1:
    Value1
  chunk tEXt at offset 0x0003d, length 12, keyword: Key2:
    Value2
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x00055, length 95
    zlib: deflated, 32K window, default compression
  chunk IEND at offset 0x000c0, length 0
No errors detected in result.png (5 chunks, 98.4% compression).
```

---

Here's how to save 3 images and a comment in a single TIFF file:

```
from PIL import Image 
from PIL.TiffImagePlugin import ImageFileDirectory_v2, TiffTags 

# Create a structure to hold meta-data
ifd = ImageFileDirectory_v2() 
ifd[270] = 'Some Funky Comment' 
ifd.tagtype[270] = TiffTags.ASCII 

# Create red image and save with metadata embedded 
im1 = Image.new('RGB',(50,50),'red') 
im2 = Image.new('RGB',(64,64),'green') 
im3 = Image.new('RGB',(80,80),'blue') 
im1.save("result.tif", append_images[im2,im3], save_all=True, tiffinfo=ifd)
```

And check that with:

```
tiffinfo -v result.tif
```

**Sample Output**

```
TIFF Directory at offset 0x8 (8)
  Image Width: 50 Image Length: 50
  Bits/Sample: 8
  Compression Scheme: None
  Photometric Interpretation: RGB color
  Samples/Pixel: 3
  Rows/Strip: 50
  Planar Configuration: single image plane
  ImageDescription: Some Funky Comment
TIFF Directory at offset 0x1e08 (7688)
  Image Width: 64 Image Length: 64
  Bits/Sample: 8
  Compression Scheme: None
  Photometric Interpretation: RGB color
  Samples/Pixel: 3
  Rows/Strip: 64
  Planar Configuration: single image plane
  ImageDescription: Some Funky Comment
TIFF Directory at offset 0x4eb8 (20152)
  Image Width: 80 Image Length: 80
  Bits/Sample: 8
  Compression Scheme: None
  Photometric Interpretation: RGB color
  Samples/Pixel: 3
  Rows/Strip: 80
  Planar Configuration: single image plane
  ImageDescription: Some Funky Comment
```

[image]

---

You can then extract the images on the command-line with **ImageMagick** like this.

To extract first image:

```
magick result.tif[0] first.png
```

To extract last image:

```
magick result.tif[-1] last.png
```

To extract all three images:

```
magick result.tif image-%d.png
```

**Result**

```
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  457 21 Jan 08:11 image-0.png
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  458 21 Jan 08:11 image-1.png
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  460 21 Jan 08:11 image-2.png
```

Note: Use `convert` in place of `magick` above if you are running v6 **ImageMagick**.

**Keywords**: Python, PIL, image processing, multiple images, TIF, comment, tiffinfo, IFD, PNG tEXt.

Comment: In the future, I will add funky comments in all of my images. :-)

Comment: @HansHirse Good - it is very important to have funky comments because they are easily spotted when gripping (searching) in files :-) And `comment=comment` is a bit boring :-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks for your nice and comprehensive answer. I would like to store the ByteIO using the normal write to binary, as I thought the that these bytes denotes the compressed image. My objective is to have a header with text, alphanumeric parameters. Not sure if storing the header of my application as comments in a file is a good idea, not to mention I am also considering implementing some text compression method on the text. Not sure if TIFF will do in this case, what do you think?  
I saw that imencode of OpenCV provides the compressed format, I'll have to give it a go n see.

Comment: You can't have a header of text and stuff at the beginning of an image. Image viewers use the first few bytes to detect the image type, height and width. It's generally not the best idea to store binary image data in the same file as text data. Maybe try and be clearer about what you actually want store and why it needs to be in a single file. Maybe you could put a few image files and a text file together in a single zipped archive?

Comment: @MarkSetchell You are right, this can not be done via the available image standards, e.g. TIFF, JPG, etc, and that's why I'm trying to do my own format. Something similar to [DICOM](https://www.dicomstandard.org/), it needs to be in a single file, without even using a zipped archive. I will of course need to take care of the file architecture and lots of other details. It would help if each encoded image (via OpenCV) is compressed and has all its header info, making it separate from the text and other info (header). Still concerned if encode of OpenCV will do.

Comment: I don't see your concern about OpenCV's `imencode()`. It will write a standard format PNG or JPEG or whatever you want into a BytesIO and you can store that however you like and later any viewer can read it. Maybe you should write your file in JSON - you could add any text and data you want and also store the image as base64-encoded string which while it may be 30% bigger than the corresponding JPEG will allow it to be stored in a text file...

Comment: Thank you Mark once again for this nice brainstorming. I believe JSON would also be slower to import / export than the binary file. Still, I like the idea and will think of which approach to choose.

Comment: Where's the magic number `270` come from in the TIFF `ImageFileDirectory_v2` example?

Comment: Hi @martineau Good point. I use this as my reference on TIFF Tags https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/search.html?q=270&Submit=Find+Tags So, you should see it is called *"Image Description"*.

Comment: Mark: Thank you, the [TIFF Tag Reference](https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags.html) looks like a good resource.