# Store extra information with TIF file

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am using PIL to store TIFF file from a bunch of images.

`tifimgs[0].save(filename, compression="tiff_deflate", save_all=True, append_images=tifimgs[1:])`

Is it possible to store extra information with the images like layer name, alpha etc without messing up the image structrue?

Comment: You can store information like that in image files via [Exif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) using a third-party modules. PIL apparently supports it, too, see the [`ExifTags` Module](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ExifTags.html#exiftags-module).

Comment: thanks, I tried adding new custom tags with but didn't work, i'll try the plugin thing.

Comment: See Mark's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59829590/11089932) for an example how to store custom data in TIFF images in Pillow.